# php how to access object array

Tags: php, arrayobject

How to access the item array from the following object array

```
Cart66Cart Object
(
[_items:Cart66Cart:private] => Array
    (
        [2] => Cart66CartItem Object
            (
                [_productId:Cart66CartItem:private] => 327
                [_quantity:Cart66CartItem:private] => 3
                [_optionInfo:Cart66CartItem:private] => 
                [_priceDifference:Cart66CartItem:private] => 0
                [_customFieldInfo:Cart66CartItem:private] => 
                [_productUrl:Cart66CartItem:private] => http://localhost/odesk/cart66/fran-wilson-aloe-lip-care/
                [_formEntryIds:Cart66CartItem:private] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [3] => Cart66CartItem Object
            (
                [_productId:Cart66CartItem:private] => 368
                [_quantity:Cart66CartItem:private] => 2
                [_optionInfo:Cart66CartItem:private] => 
                [_priceDifference:Cart66CartItem:private] => 0
                [_customFieldInfo:Cart66CartItem:private] => 
                [_productUrl:Cart66CartItem:private] => http://localhost/odesk/cart66/beauty-strokes-basic-shadow-brush/
                [_formEntryIds:Cart66CartItem:private] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

    )

[_promotion:Cart66Cart:private] => 
[_promoStatus:Cart66Cart:private] => 0
[_shippingMethodId:Cart66Cart:private] => 13
[_liveRates:Cart66Cart:private] => Cart66LiveRates Object
    (
        [toZip] => 
        [weight] => 
        [rates] => Array
            (
            )

        [_toCountryCode:protected] => 
    )

)
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to add a public getItems() function into the Cart class?

Comment: Are you asking, *"How do I access a private/protected object property?"* -or- *"How do I make an object act like an array?"*

Comment: I was asking to access the items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
$object->_items[index]->_productId
```

But if _items is private you will need a public getter or mess with the Reflection classes. You can set the the private property to be accessible through ReflectionProperty
Try this:

```
    $reflectionObject = new ReflectionObject($yourObject);
    $property = $reflectionObject->getProperty('_items');
    $property->setAccessible(true);
    $items = $property->getValue($yourObject);
```

Comment: $object->_items should return the items array. but it is not. how I can get item array. Is need to convert it to public

Comment: one thing this code was running well on local machine but giving problem on live server. any clue?

Comment: what kind of problems? make sure both machines are running the same php version

Answer (score 4):

If you *must* access a private/protected class property you can simply use the [magic `__get` method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php). Reflection would be way overboard in this case. Whether or not it makes good design sense to use the magic methods in this case depends on your situation, though.

```
class MyClass
{
    private $_items;

    public function __get($prop)
    {
        if ($prop == '_items') {
            return $this->_items;
        }
        throw new OutOfBoundsException;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

After re-reading it seems you simply want your object to behave like an array. To do this you'll need to implement [`ArrayAccess`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) and point the relevant methods to the private `$_items` property.

```
class MyClass implements ArrayAccess
{
    private $_items = array();

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_items = array(
            "one"   => 1,
            "two"   => 2,
            "three" => 3,
        );
    }
    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        if (is_null($offset)) {
            $this->_items[] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->_items[$offset] = $value;
        }
    }
    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return isset($this->_items[$offset]);
    }
    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        unset($this->_items[$offset]);
    }
    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        return isset($this->_items[$offset]) ? $this->_items[$offset] : null;
    }
}
```

And *finally*, PHP comes with a built-in [`ArrayObject`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) class that will make an object behave very much like an array. You could always use that and point the relevent methods at a private `$_items` property.

Comment: i agree with the overboard statement, but given the fact that we don't know the class interface we should consider it. Thats why reflection is for, i guess. IMHO

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$object->$first_node->$second_node->$third_node;
```

Comment: It's private, so probably not an option.