# Accessing Object Values

Tags: php

Sorry if this is a particularly stupid question but it's late and I'm going slightly round the bend on this.

I have an object returned from an API which `echo '<pre>';print_r($r);echo '</pre>';` gives as:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 49
    [submitdate] => 2015-11-05 14:33:16
    [lastpage] => 4
    [startlanguage] => en
    [Qu1[SQ001]] => Fred Bloggs
    [Qu1[SQ003]] => Caretaker
    [Feedback] => Great course, thank you
)
```

The line `echo '<p>Feedback: '.$r -> Feedback.'</p>';` displays 'Great course, thank you' as expected, but `echo '<p>'.$r -> Qu1 -> SQ001.'</p>';` doesn't show 'Fred Bloggs', instead I get an error: `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$Qu1`.

Please will somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php how to access object array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536101/php-how-to-access-object-array)

Comment: As explained above, that works for `$r -> Feedback` (and `$r -> id`), but not if I try and get the name (Fred Bloggs), I expected it to be `$r -> Qu1 -> SQ001`, but I get the error as described.

Comment: Try `$r->Qu1['SQ001']`

Comment: Sorry, still get the same error `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$Qu1`

Comment: How do you get this array?

Comment: It's part of the response provided by the Limesurvey API (`export_responses_by_token`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in two ways(may be there are more, but I know two only :))

**1)**

```
$obj['a'] = "A";
$obj['b'] = "B";
$obj['c'] = "C";
$obj['get[d]'] = "D";
$obj['get[E]'] = "E";
$obj = (object) $obj;
echo "This is: ".$obj->{'get[d]'}.PHP_EOL;
echo "This is: ".$obj->{'get[E]'}.PHP_EOL;
```

will output

```
This is: D
This is: E
```

**2)**

other is, you can get the properties of object by using [**`get_object_vars()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)
 states

> get_object_vars — Gets the properties of the given object

So,

```
$array = get_object_vars($obj); 
echo "This is: ".$array['get[E]']." but getting from array";
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/2eQB3j)**

Comment: Thank you, `$r -> {'Qu1[SQ001]'}` worked. I've not come across this syntax before - can you point me towards an explanation?

Comment: @EssexSteph: can't find much explanations, look here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333016/how-to-access-object-properties-with-names-like-integers

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> $r -> Qui[SQ001]

Qui looks to be an array so $r -> Qui -> SQ001 won't work