# Get information out of PHP array in to single values in a loop

Tags: php, arrays

```
    SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [deelnemer] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [startnummer] => A1
                        [naam] => Jerry
                        [adres] => Straat 38
                        [postcode] => 0000 MC
                        [woonplaats] => Tilburg
                        [land] => NED
                        [geboortedatum] => 27-02-1988
                        [geslacht] => M
                        [categorie] => Heren
                        [onderdeel] => E. 10 Miles - start 15u00
                    )

                [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object


                    (
                        [startnummer] => A2
                        [naam] => Wesley
                        [adres] => straat 13
                        [postcode] => 0000 AJ
                        [woonplaats] => Tilburg
                        [land] => NED
                        [geboortedatum] => 20-04-1979
                        [geslacht] => M
                        [categorie] => Heren
                        [onderdeel] => E. 10 Miles - start 15u00
                    )

            )
    )
```

I have this array. I need per 'deelnemer' the individual values.
I tried:

```
echo '<select>';
foreach ($xml as $obj)
{
    foreach ($obj['deelnemer'] as $ob)
    {

            echo '<option value='.$ob['naam'].'>'.$ob['naam'].'</option>';

    }
}
echo '</select>';
```

But i keep getting error messages. The only thing i can substract atm is 'deelnemer'.

I need a PHP code to create a loop (for each) with a dropdown select with the names of the participants.

Comment: "I keep getting error messages" - mind sharing those with us?

Comment: PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Answer (score 4):

$xml is not an array but an object, so in order to access its elements use **->** instead of [] as explained in [php how to access object array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536101/php-how-to-access-object-array)

Try this code:

```
echo '<select>';
foreach ($xml->deelnemer as $ob) {
  echo '<option value="' . $ob->naam . '">' . $ob->naam . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Thanks for your information. 
The result is:
<select><option value=></option><option value=></option> </select>

--

The name isnt showing

Comment: $ob is an object as well.

Comment: echo '<select>';
foreach ($xml->deelnemer as $ob) {
  echo '<option value='.$ob->naam.'>'.$ob->naam.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';

works, thank you