# PHP unable to read object

Tags: php, object

My object received to variable `$data` from an API looks like this:

```
        Data Object
        (
            [serviceContext:DataService:private] => ServiceContext Object
                (
                    [info1] => abcde
                    [serviceType] => 123
                 )
        )
```

I want to retrive `info1`

I tried `echo $data->serviceContext:DataService:private;`
but that seems to be a syntax error caused by the `:`

I tried `echo $data->serviceContext->info1`; which results in:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access private property Data::$serviceContext
```

What's the correct way to retrieve the elements? Thank you

Comment: `var_dump($data->serviceContext);` what do you see?

Comment: Consider looking at the methods for the object; you do have a class definition don't you? Perhaps in the API documentation

Comment: `Cannot access private property` This is a private property. You want to be using a *get* method to view this property.

Comment: You're attempting to access a `private` data member of an object from outside of the object. This isn't possible. Look into `public` vs. `private` in objects. Instead, you will want to find the appropriate `public` object method to get this value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20334749/4248328  And   https://stackoverflow.com/a/10536163/4248328

Comment: Do you see where it says `private`? The error message is saying you cannot access `$serviceContext`, why? because its private.